# Query Google Maps for surrounding cities to a location

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am new to using Google Maps API. I have a problem that I want to solve. I have a ZIP code and city name and an input and I want to get the names and ZIP codes of all the cities surrounding the input in a specific radius.

Is there a way to do this using Google Maps API or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2):

No. The Google Maps API doesn't have a proximity search. You can make yourself one with the harvesine formula or a space filling curve, i.e. a spatial index.

Answer (score 0):

Proximity search/nearby places isn't part of the Google Maps API. However there are third-party providers that may meet your requirement. The first that comes to mind is [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/), this [webservice](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearbyPlaceName) seems like it might be what you are looking for.

[Example](http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=47.3&lng=9&radius=50&maxRows=10&username=demo)

Answer (score 0):

While it's not available, you might try with the Places API, searching for something unique (ie 1 per city) in a set radius. Maybe try with a search for "city hall" around ZIP code XXXXX, radius 30 mi. See if that yields valid results.